# Designing and Implementing a Sphere in Java

Tags: java, geometry

I'm trying to get off to a good start with programming. The instructor of a class isn't providing feedback, so I'm reaching to you guys for some direction and help if I'm on the right track. Below you will find the assignment prompt and below that you will find what I've done. Does the code that I have successfully incorporate the requirements? I'm using NetBeans and it will run, but I can't figure out if I'm misplacing modifiers or inputting bad formal parameters, or anything for that matter. I have zero feedback, would appreciate some help!

**Design and implement a class called Sphere that contains instance data that represents the sphere’s diameter. Define the Sphere constructor to accept and initialize the diameter, and include getter and setter methods for the diameter. Include methods that calculate and return the volume and surface area of the sphere (see programming project 3.5 for the formulas). Include a toString method that returns a one-line description of the sphere. Create a driver class called MultiSphere, whose main method instantiates and updates several Sphere objects.**

```
package sphere;

public class Sphere {

private int diameter, radius;
private double volume, surfArea;


    public Sphere(int diam){
        diam = diameter;
    }

    //Diameter mutator.
    public void setDiameter(int value){
        if (value > 0)
            diameter = value;
    }

    //Diameter accessor.
    public int getDiameter(){
        return diameter;
    }

    //Radius mutator.
    public void setRadius(int value){
        radius = (int)diameter / 2;
    }

    //Radius accessor.
    public int getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }

    //Calculate volume.
    public double getVolume(int radius){
        volume = (double)(Math.pow(radius,3)* Math.PI *(4.0/3.0) );
        return volume;
    }

    //Calculate surface area.
    public double getSurfArea(int radius){
        surfArea = (double)(Math.pow(radius,2)*Math.PI * 4.0);
        return surfArea;
    }

    //Results in string
    public String toStrings(){
        String result1 = Integer.toString(diameter);
        String result2 = Double.toString(volume);
        String result3 = Double.toString(surfArea);
        return result1 + result2 + result3;
    }
```

Comment: `"Does the code that I have successfully incorporate the requirements?"` -- what happens when you run and test your code?

Comment: The requirements seem clear-does it meet them?

Comment: When the code is run, it states I'm missing the main method. At this point do I incorporate a main method with a scanner? If so, do I first import the scanner then construct the scanner, then scan for the nextInt()? If so, how do I use this nextInt value to generate all my results, in other words, what would it look like to compile all these methods correctly with the input value?

Comment: Also, by doing everything I just mentioned below, am I satisfying or deviating from the requirements? Lastly, for MultiSphere.. do I create a new class in the same java doc as a sub class or just a new class and java doc within the same project? How do I invoke these methods to modify the Sphere objects. Would this be a constructor, then method, with ability to accept a new diameter value and copy/paste the logic to print the new results? Or is this the point? They can be accessed publicly, not just public at the class level but out of the java doc? This is confusing...

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues :

1. getVolume and getSurfArea don't require a radius argument, since the sphere already has a getRadius() method.
2. You don't need `setRadius` since you can calculate the radius from the diameter.
3. There's no need to store volume, surfArea & radius as members of the class, since all of them can be calculated based on the diameter property.
4. `toStrings()` should be `toString()`, and you should probably format the output better (for example, add spaces or other delimeters).

Comment: Thanks for the help Eran. I think although the methods I have are redundant (for ex. radius and aren't really needed), they were good practice. I believe the assignment mentions to create methods for surfArea and Volume, this why I went this route. Should I have done this different while still having satisfied a "method" approach?